# How to solve 'cannot open file 'cutil32D.lib' error in VS2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, cuda

I'm trying to build cuda-convnet project from Win10 OS with VS2010, any idea how to solve the ' LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'cutil32D.lib'

(I'm following the steps indicated in this page: http://vision.group.shef.ac.uk/wordpress/?p=1)

Note: 
I found in an older post that I should build the common folder in the main samples folder, I chose to build a VS2010 solution but nothing have changed unfortunately..

EDIT:
I just discovered that my machine doesn't have Nvidia -enabled GPU, that's why the code didn't work.

Comment: I already mentioned that I found a similar question, though I don't know how to proceed; the proposed solution in the similar post didn't work for me. Can someone clarify what should I do after I build the SDK VS2010 solution?

Comment: cutil32D means 32 bit, with debugging symbols. You must have an available build for those compilation settings before linkage can work

Comment: My system is 64bit, how do I find the available build? I used the solution samples found in: C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v5.5